# Parse excel document string without file path in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way or a gem to parse an xlsx document string without having a file? I was using Roo to parse the excel file when it was on my local machine but I would like to do it without downloading the actual document. I receive it in my google mailbox, and can pull the excel document string but can't find any way to parse just the string without a file path. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to wrap your string in a [`StringIO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) object that will expose a similar API as File objects. Unfortunately, it looks like Roo has a lot of file handling built in to the various classes, and expects a pathname in the `initialize` method. As I see it you have a few options:

1. Subclass one of Roo's spreadsheet classes to override the file handling, and substitute in your StringIO object.
2. Save the string to a [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) and pass the temporary path into one of Roo's standard initializers (I suspect this would be easier to implement).

Answer (score 0):

You can not parse a file without supplying it to your parser.

So at one point or another you will have to download the file, so that the parser has anything he can read for parsing.